# How to use the code '.Copy destination:=' on protected sheets

Tags: excel, vba

When I am trying to Copy/paste rows from 2 protected sheet, I got an error:1004 saying that it can't paste because the sheets are protected, even though i have the code line `sheetname.Protect "password",Userinterfaceonly:=True` applied on both sheets when protecting them

The example Code I used that give me an error is :
`Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1").Copy Worksheet("Sheet2").Range("A1")`

But when I write it like the following, it works just fine :

```
Worksheet("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1").Copy
Worksheet("Sheet2").Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues)
```

I like to use the first code because it does not show selected cells after pasting the data.
Is it not possible to use this code on protected sheet or am I missing something, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**Edited**: I forgot to mention something, based on your comments below, is it possible to use this method on visible cells, ex:

```
Sheet1.Range("A2:E3") = Sheet2.Range("A2:E10").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
```

,given that there are 2 filtered/visible rows in Sheet2, explaining the reason why I put the range **A2:E3**

Comment: If you only want values, just assign the value property of one range to the Value property of the other rather than copying at all.

Comment: It looks that your protected sheet does not allow copying the format. Do you need the format?

Comment: Try `Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:D1").Value = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D1").Value ` You are using `xlPasteValues` so I guess you need only the values. This should work for you

Comment: @FaneDuru No, I do not need the format, in fact I use this line to protect the sheets `Sheet1.Protect "password", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, userinterfaceonly:=True`